# Range(Cells(... working incorrectly

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have a little problem with a VBA range being used in excel:

```
dim frameRefPoint As String

frameRefPoint = "4,4"
range(Cells(frameRefPoint).Offset(0,0), Cells(frameRefPoint).Offset(7, 7)).Interior ...
```

This isn't behaving as I expect it to. I think that the first cell in the specified `Range(Cells(4,4).Offset(0,0))` should be "D4", but when I use the range in a code, the first cell of the range is "D1" ~ cells(1,4).

The address property of *cells(frameRefPoint)* returns $D$1. What am I missing here?

Comment: `"4,4"` is a string, not a VBA parameter list.

Comment: do you must use `frameRefPoint = "4,4"` ? you can't just use `frameRefPoint = "D4"`?

Comment: @ShaiRado I need to increment (move in a direction) - a variable representing a cell address, eg. I have cellAdress = "C4" and I need to move it by 3 rows down. Was much easier with cells(4,4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot span two paramters (e.g. `.Cells(<row>, <column>)`) by concatenating the values with an interim comma. Just making it 'look' like what you code is not the same as legitimate code. You *can* however, use variables for each parameter.

```
dim r as long, c as long, frameRefPoint As string
r = 4
c = 4
cells(r, c).resize(7, 7) = "this works"

frameRefPoint = "4,4"
'split the string on the comma and convert teh text-that-looks-numbers to actual numbers
cells(int(split(frameRefPoint, ",")(0))), int(split(frameRefPoint, ",")(1)).resize(7, 7) = "this also works"
```

Comment: Use `.Resize(7, 7)` to expand the initial cell to 7 rows by 7 columns. Using `.offset(0, 0)` and `.offset(7, 7)` to expand the region seems like messy code.

Comment: I understand the problem now, thank you. I will check how .resize behaves, never knew it existed.

Comment: Actually, `.resize(8, 8)` would be the same as `.offset(0, 0)` and `.offset(7, 7)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Range(Cells(CInt(Split(frameRefPoint, ",")(0)), CInt(Split(frameRefPoint, ",")(1))).Offset(0, 0), Cells(CInt(Split(frameRefPoint, ",")(0)), CInt(Split(frameRefPoint, ",")(1))).Offset(7, 7)).Interior....
```